# grid layout structure

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, grid-layout

I installed theme "A" in magento 1.9.3 it looked good but the image size and grid layout was not good or even. I then installed theme "B" that had a good image size and grid layout but the rest wasn't good.

I switched back to theme "A" and the image size and grid layout was now good.

Are there specific files I can copy from theme B into the folders for theme A to enforce the good grid layout and image size?

I have noticed that installing specific extensions that I require causes the layout to return to the default theme "A" problems. I expect that if the theme "B" files were placed locally in the theme "A"'s directory structure the good parts of theme "A" and theme "B" would be retained.  The particular issues are category grid layout and detail page image size.

Answer (score 0):

A good answer to this is next to impossible without a thorough examination of both theme's template files.

I would advise finding a Magento developer with some theming experience who can take a look at this for you. Downside is that this could take a lot of time so probably won't be free.

Regards,
Vincent